# MultiBinding tag generating a "does not exist in the namespace" error

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, binding

```
<UserControl x:Class="PeepsAndPals.View.PeepView_CompleteListOfSeenPeeps"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TypeName" Text="{Binding Path=Type.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
                                    <Binding Path="Geocord.Latitude"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Geocord.Longitude"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I build this code in Visual Studio I get the error 'The name "MultiBinding" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007".' It's especially weird because if you look at the xmlns' at the top, 2007 is not in any of them. There's a couple 2006's and a couple 2008's.

I looked at a couple people who had similar problems:

1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a4602cde-3416-41bf-9df8-613db99b6ce6/the-tag-multibinding-does-not-exist-in-xml-namespace?forum=wpf <- But my tag is spelled correctly.
2. [Keep getting error: The tag does not exist in XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128062/keep-getting-error-the-tag-does-not-exist-in-xml-namespace) <- But I'm not using a converter. I'm using string.Format().

I also checked the msdn docs for multibinding. I added 'using System.Windows.Data' to the code behind and temporarily added the 2007 version of the xmlns listed to see if that would fix the issue but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Silverlight 3 (used by Windows Phone) doesn't support MultiBinding. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968247/622391) references a workaround.

Comment: I'll do the solution where I extend the view model. When you click on the link you provided, they first suggest another work around link and that link points to a page that doesn't exist anymore. Thanks for the help :)